# Jquery Globalize and JavaScript Globalize breaks Jquery client side Validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, unobtrusive-validation

I added Jquery-validation-globalize and globalize.js into my _ValidationScriptsPartial view in my ASP.NET Core (5.0) project.
By doing so, I lost functionality provided by Jquery-validate.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js scripts
That is, I am able to use numbers, dates, etc in the desired culture, as provided by the globalize scripts, but I lost client side validation.
All the validation works, but only in serve side.
I followed instructions from this github issue:

https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/4076#issuecomment-326590420

For reference, this is how I coded the scripts (they all exist in the mentioned folders):

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/site.js"></script>    
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/cldrjs/dist/cldr.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/cldrjs/dist/cldr/event.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/cldrjs/dist/cldr/supplemental.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/globalize/dist/globalize.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/globalize/dist/globalize/number.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/globalize/dist/globalize/date.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/globalize/dist/globalize/currency.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/globalize/dist/globalize/message.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/globalize/dist/globalize/unit.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/globalize/dist/globalize/plural.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/globalize/dist/globalize/relative-time.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-globalize/jquery.validate.globalize.js"></script>
```

Comment: See this comment in the same thread https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/4076#issuecomment-366162798

Comment: @LazZiya, thank you very much, the solution worked. I just had to update some references to the json files and bower. I posted a comment in the github issue with the detailed updates.